# Primefaces selectBooleanCheckbox - true value without check mark

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I found out an abnormal output of `p:selectBooleanCheckbox` in Primefaces on my JSF page. It works correctly but looks unusual, when set up to `true` it just changes its color without check mark:

False value:

[image]

True value:

[image]

The code is ordinary:

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="readiness" value="#{employeeBean.newEmployee.ready}" required="true"/>
```

How to set up the normal checkmark symbol [✓] inside a box?

Comment: This is not the default behavior. How exactly can we reproduce this when having only a scratchpad project with everything set to bare defaults and using most recent versions? Sure your CSS isn't being messed up? It's using a CSS background image for that.

Comment: Thank you BalusC! You gave me a right direction - point is that was the CSS class:
.ui-icon {
    border-radius: 0 !important;
    background-position: top right;
}
that I used for button icons.
Question is resolved.